# Primary Key with different value depending on insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, prefix

i have a table like this

```
create table tower (
    d_tower int(10) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar (20) not null
)
```

and when i insert something like Tower it had T001 as the primary key or when i insert Radio it had R001 as the primary key. how should i have to do for that ?

Comment: You can't do that with a primary key that is `auto_increment`.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT has to be an integer, not a string.

Comment: You can use a generated column whose expression is `CONCAT(LEFT(name, 1), LPAD(d_tower, 10, '0'))`

Comment: my bad it seem i need to change the type of the primary key to int,and when i alrdy done that,what is the next steps to do what is stated above ?

Comment: Autoincremented column must have numeric datatype and it must be primary key. The primary key which you need must have a string datatype - so autoincrement is not applicable for your task. So you need to generate numeric part of your primary key using code. In theory it can be performed in a trigger, but this is problematic when concurrent inserts are possible. I'd recommend to create stored procedure which receives the data to be inserted and generates the value for primary key column. PS. There exists an alternative - but only when the table is defined as `ENGINE=MyISAM`.